# Change Name of ActiveX Command Button using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, command

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638620/reference-to-command-buttons-added-during-runtime-with-vba-in-excel)

I am trying to change the name property of ActiveX command buttons with VBA with the following code:

```
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)

With shp.OLEFormat.Object
    .Object.Caption = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
    .Name = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
End With
```

I am able to change the caption name, but the name property cannot be changed with the above code. I need to find a way to concatenate a string with an int (NumNodes) for the name property.

**UPDATE**

This is the full subroutine which copies a command button and pastes it to a specific cell location. Properties, such as the name and caption are also changed upon button creation.

```
Public Sub Node_Button_Duplication()
'
'Comments: Copies and pastes Node 1's button to the appropriate column

Dim shp As Shape

' Copy Node 1 button and paste in appropriate location

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(5, 10 + 7 * (NumNodes - 1) - 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 47.25
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -13.5


    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)

    With shp.OLEFormat.Object
        .Object.Caption = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
        .Name = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
shp.Name = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)

With shp.OLEFormat.Object
    .Object.Caption = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
End With
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Just tried this and it works...

```
Public Sub Node_Button_Duication()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim NumNodes As Long

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(5, 10 + 7 * (NumNodes - 1) - 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 47.25
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -13.5

    NumNodes = 5

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
    shp.Name = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)

    With shp.OLEFormat.Object
        .Object.Caption = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
    End With
End Sub
```

**MORE FOLLOWUP**

Try this

```
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)

    With shp.OLEFormat.Object
        .Object.Caption = "Node" & Str(NumNodes)
        .Name = "Node" & NumNodes
    End With
```

Notice, I changed `Str(NumNodes)` to `NumNodes`?

The ActiveX Control Names cannot have spaces :)

Try now.

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Yes. The result is that the command button name stays as "CommandButton4".

Comment: I just tried it. It changes the name of the newly created command button

Comment: Are you sure it changes both the **NAME** and **Caption** and not only the **Caption**? In VB editor the name field still says CommandButton4 after button creation

Comment: Such a simple fix. Why didn't I try that! Thanks again for your help! Much appreciated!