# Make vba code work for all boxes

Tags: excel, vba

Hello so what i want to do is make this code work for all Check Box's 1-50 I want the code to only effect the box that is clicked.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If MsgBox("Do you want to lock this box?", vbYesNo, "Warning") = vbYes Then
  ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Enabled = False
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to disable the check box when its clicked? And why it is not working if the check boxes are a part of collection?

Comment: It disables the check box when it is clicked i just don't want to make code for every box. I also do not want it to lock Every Check box when one is click, only the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I see several options (none of which are pretty since this is VBA).

- **Option 1**: generate the code for all of your check boxes. This is probably the most maintainable. You would first choose reasonable names for all your check boxes (you can assign them by selecting them in Excel and renaming in the top left corner, or run code which will do this for you if you already have a lot of check boxes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641683/change-name-of-activex-command-button-using-vba-in-excel) may be useful).

  You can then generate the code and have each one of your subprocedues as follows:

  ```
  'example code for one checkbox
  Private Sub chkBox_1_Click()
      Call lockMeUp(Sheet1.chkBox_1.Object)
  End Sub
  ```

  After you're done with all your code for each checkbox, you could have your `lockMeUp` subprocedure as follows:

  ```
  Sub lockMeUp(chkBox as Object)
      If MsgBox("Do you want to lock this box?", vbYesNo, "Warning") = vbYes Then
          chkBox.Enabled = False
      End If
  End Sub
  ```
- **Option 2**: Keep track of all your checked/unchecked statuses through either an Array or a "Settings" hidden sheet, and watch out for that triggered event. You could fire off based off of a sheet's `Changed` event, and match the row number to your CheckBox number so that you can go off of the `Target`'s row number.

Other options I can think of become more convoluted... I'd be interested to see what other suggestions people have. Thanks!

**EDIT** You can use some code to refer to a single function as in my example, in conjunction with brettdj's example to get your optimal solution. Bam!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to write a `class module` that will apply one code routine to a collection of `Checkboxes`

Assuming yu want to run this on all ActiveX checkboxes on the `ActiveSheet`, then borrowing heavily from Bob Phillip's [code from VBAX](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?4806-Solved-ActiveX-Checkboxes-on-Worksheet)

1. Insert a *Class Module* named `clsActiveXEvents`

   Option Explicit

   ```
   Public WithEvents mCheckboxes As MSForms.CheckBox

   Private Sub mCheckboxes_Click()
     mCheckboxes.Enabled = (MsgBox("Do you want to lock this box?", vbYesNo, "Warning") = vbNo)
   End Sub
   ```
2. In a  *normal module* use this code

   ```
   Dim mcolEvents As Collection

   Sub Test()
   Dim cCBEvents As clsActiveXEvents
   Dim shp As Shape

   Set mcolEvents = New Collection

   For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
       If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
           If TypeName(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
              Set cCBEvents = New clsActiveXEvents
              Set cCBEvents.mCheckboxes = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
           mcolEvents.Add cCBEvents
       End If
   End If
   Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: This will fail if there are any OPtionButtons on the sheet: I guess its a bug in TypeOf. Also, I am curious why you use the Shapes and not the OLEObjects collection. Is this a backward compatibility thing?

Comment: ... I did think of using `TypeName` for this reason, but I left the code as per the original code. Its a fair point, I will update

Comment: @coolblue see [this](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showpost.php?s=83f9a2303ac55fe5fbe871ad33202eeb&p=1343879&postcount=4)

Comment: there you go... thanks, its always nice to see someone else make the same observation. I only found out by accident when I was testing my answer. At first I thought ah Ha! thats why he's using shapes... but the shapes had the exact same behaviour of course...

Comment: So what is your thinking on using Shapes instead of OLEObjects?

Comment: @CoolBlue I ran with Bob's code as is (having tested it). I concur that use of the `OLEObject` would be clearer when working with `ActiveX` controls, but I did enjoy the different method used here.

Comment: Yep, me too. OK, I was just curious... always looking to learn!

Comment: @CoolBlue have I seen you on another forum? you know your stuff

Comment: Thanks mate, I've been hitting a lot of these forums so probably... I just updated my profile to include my location: take a look :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44530/discussion-between-brettdj-and-cool-blue)

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not know, all Form Controls are treated as Shapes in a Worksheet.

I have a solution that you need to create a new Module, copy-paste in code below and then from Immediate window to the same module. With some assumptions:

- All Check Box Objects are named "**Check Box #**" where **#** is a number
- No macro named **ResetCheckBoxes()** in any other modules of the workbook
- No macro named **CheckBox#_Click()** in any other modules of the workbook

Run this **ResetCheckBoxes** once to enable check boxes and Assign a macro to it for you, with relevant generated codes in the immediate window (you might want to put a pause in the loop every 25 check boxes as line buffer in it are limited).

```
Sub ResetCheckBoxes()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oSh As Shape, sTmp As String

    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For Each oSh In oWS.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .Type = msoFormControl Then
                If InStr(1, .Name, "Check Box", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    .ControlFormat.Enabled = True
                    sTmp = "CheckBox" & Replace(oSh.Name, "Check Box ", "") & "_Click"
                    .OnAction = sTmp
                    Debug.Print "Sub " & sTmp & "()"
                    Debug.Print vbTab & "ActiveSheet.Shapes(""" & .Name & """).ControlFormat.Enabled = False"
                    Debug.Print "End Sub" & vbCrLf
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Example Immediate window output (2 test check boxes):
[image: GeneratedCodes]

Happy New Year mate!

Answer (score 0):

To build on the solution offered by @brettdj, since he is specifying ActiveX Controls, I would suggest the following in the Standard Module:

```
Dim mcolEvents As Collection
Sub Test()
Dim cCBEvents As clsActiveXEvents
Dim o As OLEObject

Set mcolEvents = New Collection

For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(o.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        Set cCBEvents = New clsActiveXEvents
        Set cCBEvents.mCheckboxes = o.Object
        mcolEvents.Add cCBEvents, o.Name
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The differences are:

1. I use the `OLEObjects` `Collection` because it is more direct and doesn't waste time on non-OLE shapes.
2. I use `TypeName` instead of (the mysterious) `TypeOf` operator because (apparently) the later does not discriminate between `OptionButton` and `CheckBox`.
3. I register the Object `Name` as `Key` in the `Collection` to allow for efficient indexing if required.

EDIT:
I should have followed the link provided by @brettdj before posting.  My solution is using the same principles as are outlined there.  Hopefully, its convenient to have it documented here as well?